# How to create a table in latex?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am new to latex, I have a simple question I want to create a table as given in picture.
[image]en,

please help me.

Comment: Wikibooks provides an excellent introduction into creating tables: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Maybe the data are  R results? In this case, there are alternatives to make the table manually ...

Comment: thanks, Vincent Kuhlmann for your valuable comment, I study your suggested book for failed to find the particular which I needed.

Comment: Thanks, Fran for your response,I am trying to create manually but did not create so for.

Comment: Use one of these tools: https://www.tablesgenerator.com or https://www.latex-tables.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pattern for your table is like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Model & Hour & MAE & MAPE & RMSE & Hour & MAE & MAPE & RMSE\\
        \hline
        NPFFAR & \multirow{3}{*}{01} & 4.29 & 8.79 & 6.06 & \multirow{3}{*}{13} & 5.08 & 12.24 & 7.10\\
        FFAR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
        ARIMA & & 4.10 & 8.82 & 5.86 & & 4.59 & 10.48 & 6.25\\
        \hline
        NPFFAR & \multirow{3}{*}{02} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & \multirow{3}{*}{14} & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
        \vdots && \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \medskip

    \begin{tabular}{ccccc|cccc}
        \toprule
        Model & Hour & MAE & MAPE & RMSE & Hour & MAE & MAPE & RMSE\\
        \midrule
        NPFFAR & \multirow{3}{*}{01} & 4.29 & 8.79 & 6.06 & \multirow{3}{*}{13} & 5.08 & 12.24 & 7.10\\
        FFAR & & 4.53 & 9.18 & 6.15 & & 5.50 & 12.35 & 7.19\\
        ARIMA & & 4.10 & 8.82 & 5.86 & & 4.59 & 10.48 & 6.25\\
        \midrule
        NPFFAR & \multirow{3}{*}{02} & 4.21 & 9.81 & 5.64 & \multirow{3}{*}{14} & 5.68 & 13.38 & 7.76\\
        \vdots && \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs
[image: Tables in LaTeX]

The second `tabular` (the one with `\toprule` and such) makes use of the `booktabs` package. That often produces nicer looking tables. Keep the `tabular` you like, and remove the other one.

I hope this code gives you a good start in working with tables. If you want something more, first try to accomplish it yourself by searching online. People active on this forum do so in their free time, we can't make everyone's documents.

Has this answer helped you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vincent Kuhlman yes it really works as required.

Comment: @user243550 Great! Make sure to mark the question as answered too, so other people know this question has been answered already

Comment: Since your second, `booktabs`-based example conteins a vertical line: please kaap in mind that the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package were designed to be used in tables *without* vertical lines. Hence the small gaps around the intersections.

Comment: @leandriis Yes I know. But since the table was made to be clearly two halves, I figured this was better than nothing. And personally, I quite like this style of the gaps. Alternatives could be trying to get extra horizontal space instead of this rule or splitting the table into two halves.